# How to disable auto scroll on Scrollviewer for child controls

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have the following fairly simple code

```
  <Window ... Width=400 Height=400>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  >
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     Margin="0,5,0,5"
                     Width="500"
                     Padding="20">Scrolling is enabled when it is necessary. 
                Resize the window, making it larger and smaller.</TextBox>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="aswkognweklng"></Label>
                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         Margin="0,5,0,5"
                         Width="500"
                         Padding="20">Scrolling is enabled when it is necessary. 
                Resize the window, making it larger and smaller.</TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Window>
```

I want to disable the following behavior:

- the scrollbar is visible
- click on the text in first textbox
- click on padding area in second textbox

=> the scrollviewer will move the scrollbar so that the textbox left border is aligned with the visible window border

I would like to disable this auto scrolling behavior. Is that possible?

The default scrolling behavior with user interaction should still be working. So when the user interacts with the scrollbar it should scroll the content just normal.

[image: First textbox click]
[image: After click in padding area]

Comment: The scroll behavior is triggered by the `FrameworkElement.RequestBringIntoViewEvent`. It is a Routed Event and is raised when `FrameworkElement.BringIntoView` is invoked (which is called by the focus handler `FrameworkElement.OnGotFocus`). The parent `ScrollViewer` subscribes to this event and handles it by centering the child element which is the event source relative to the viewport.

Comment: If only need to show text, then better use a `TextBlock`. It has less performance impact and doesn't trigger the scroll into view behavior of the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: @BionicCode I need to be able to edit the text too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes It is possible. You just need to handle the RequestBringIntoView event of the `ScrollViewer` bubbling down to the second `StackPanel`. Just mark it as handled.

**XAML:**

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  >
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Margin="0,5,0,5"
                 Width="500"
                 Padding="20">Scrolling is enabled when it is necessary. 
            Resize the window, making it larger and smaller.</TextBox>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" RequestBringIntoView="StackPanel_RequestBringIntoView">
            <Label Content="aswkognweklng"></Label>
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     Margin="0,5,0,5"
                     Width="500"
                     Padding="20">Scrolling is enabled when it is necessary. 
            Resize the window, making it larger and smaller.</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**C#:**

```
private void StackPanel_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description of the  problem right you can use:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  >...
```

Or maybe a `Grid` is more what you want:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <TextBox 
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    Height="100"
    Margin="0,5,0,5"
    Padding="20">Scrolling is enabled when it is necessary. 
            Resize the window, making it larger and smaller.</TextBox>
    <Label 
      Content="aswkognweklng"
      Grid.Column="0"
      Grid.Row="1">         
    </Label>
    <TextBox 
      TextWrapping="Wrap"
      AcceptsReturn="True"
      Height="100"
      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      Margin="0,5,0,5"
      Grid.Column="1"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Padding="20">Scrolling is enabled when it is necessary. 
            Resize the window, making it larger and smaller.</TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The default scrolling behavior with user interaction should still be working. So when the user interacts with the scrollbar it should scroll the content just normal.