# Prevent TabControl from automatically scrolling down when containg a ContentControl

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application which uses a TabControl with TabItems. Some of those tabs are quite big, so scrolling is necessary. I have a ScrollViewer outside of the TabControl because I want the whole Page to scroll, not only the tab content. This worked fine for a long time, but now I added a ContentControl in one of my tabs, and if I click on that tab, the whole page is scrolling down automatically.

This seems to occur only when a tab contains enough content to make the whole page scrollable, and  if it contains a ContentControl.

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <StackPanel>
    <TabControl>
      <TabItem Header="1" />

      <TabItem Header="2">
        <ContentControl />
      </TabItem>

      <TabItem Header="3">
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Height="1000"/>
          <ContentControl />
        </StackPanel>
      </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If I use this in a new WPF app, I can  see that clicking on tab 2 works fine,  clicking on tab 3 triggers a scroll. If either the ContentControl is removed, or the height of the TextBlock is reduced, everything works fine.

Is there a way to avoid the scrolling behaviour?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56946032/3137337

Comment: Thanks for the link, setting e.Handled=true in RequestBringIntoView indeed fixes this behaviour :)